# Ps4 gameshare download

Tags: ps4, psn

I'm gamesharing with a friend on ps4. I set his account as primary on my ps4 and he put my account as primary on his ps4. He downloaded a dlc for a game that I want to download. I have one he wants to download. The game has a lock next to it and will not let us download it. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The account that purchases the content will need to perform the download/install on the system before the guest/alternate account can access the content.